# Is the incentive to answer (rather than flag) low quality questions too strong?

Tags: discussion, answers

We have a frequent influx of low quality questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796316/what-does-in-front-of-a-word-mean-in-ruby), we spend quite a bit of time discussing how to deal with it, and there is a rather strong disincentive for posting them, as they normally are met with a flurry of down votes, and—when appropriate—flagging.

What we don't discuss all that much, however, is the tendency for people to poach on these questions, and quickly post make-shift answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796316/what-does-in-front-of-a-word-mean-in-ruby/33796353#33796353), instead of flagging.

Sadly, these answers consistently seem to rake in some points, often more so than well researched and carefully crafted ones to more obscure problems. In this case, the answer was not even an acceptable one by SO standards.

There is already a tendency for answers to specific and hard questions to go unrewarded, while generic and trivial ones offer a far superior reward for the effort (or lack thereof) involved, and I'm afraid this only further acts to skew the efforts of the community towards the latter.

So how can we provide a better incentive to flag rather than go for free points? And should we?

Comment: see [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @gnat. Some great content in there.

Comment: Pretty biased as long as you don't also consider whether the incentive to ask bad questions isn't too high.  SO is well past the point where it can still be effectively moderated, the questioners are now firmly in the driver-seat and determine content.  Are they doing a good job of it?  Should they be treated like children that can't be responsible because they don't know any better?  Why would a new user that likes to contribute assume that he's responsible when clearly there are so many that are not?

Answer (score -2):

We're not always fast enough to close off-topic questions and that means that people are still free to answer them any way they see fit.

> In this case, the answer was not even an acceptable one by SO standards.

If you feel this way (and I tend to agree with you, it's not much better than a link-only answer), flag the answer as "Not an answer". If enough people do that, it will show up in the review queues and likely still be deleted.

> So how can we provide a better incentive to flag rather than go for free points? And should we?

It's a fair question, but I don't think there is a good way to discourage people from answering such questions. And I'm also not sure if we should. Obviously "low quality" is a matter of opinion in the end, not everyone might see a question as being low quality. There are always some factors that weigh in on the quality of a question, but in the end it should be reviewed case-by-case and all factors considered, a decision should then be made by several peer reviewers. It's almost never the opinion of a single person. As long as the question is open, I don't see why anybody shouldn't answer it, if they feel they can help the OP.

I also doubt if people answer questions for "raking points", they are probably just trying to help. I don't think we should discourage that. It's the essence of SO to help each other out. You shouldn't make the threshold to answer a question too high for people, because that would collapse the community very quickly, I imagine.

Comment: You should not be flagging answers as NAA just becuase it's not up to SO's quality standards.  You should only be using NAA if it's not an answer at all, which is not the case here.